# Fetch values through a junction table using joins

Tags: python, mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables: users, users_book and book, I didn't have a standard naming convention at the start so please excuse that.

I want to display all values in book using just the userID value, I've been reading about doing joins and have tried the following:

```
SELECT book.bookname AS "Book Name", author
   FROM users_book
       JOIN users ON users_book.userId = users.userId
       JOIN book ON users_book.book_id = book.book_id
   WHERE author IS NOT NULL
```

However I haven't been able to display anything using that.

Comment: What do you mean by "haven't been able to display anything"? Is there an error or the output is wrong?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this is for python flask, so by display I mean display on the python rendered html.

Comment: Have you checked if the query is producing the correct results? Maybe the problem is in the code an not the Query?

Comment: @MD.TabishMahfuz I've run the code you posted with the added WHERE condition and it is running correctly, I suppose the issue I'm having now is just it displaying using flask.

Comment: Glad that worked!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a userId which you want to send as parameter to the query then this should work:

```
    SELECT users_book.userid, book.bookname AS "Book Name", author 
        FROM users_book 
        JOIN book ON users_book.book_id = book.book_id 
        WHERE author IS NOT NULL 
             AND users_book.userId = USER_ID
```

Replace the `USER_ID` with your userId parameter